# Apache mod_evasive not respecting configurations in Virtual host for specific pages in Drupal

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-evasive

I've setup mod_evasive in Apache for my Drupal 9 website by adding configurations in the Virtual host file as follows

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
    DOSSiteCount 50
    DOSSiteInterval 1
    DOSPageCount 10
    DOSPageInterval 1
    DOSBlockingPeriod 120
</IfModule>
```

This works perfectly fine for most/all of the pages in the application except for the **PHP status** page */admin/reports/status/php*. For this page, it seems to ignore the above configs and fallback to default values. I get 403 error on every subsequent page refresh

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to find the root cause, but the workaround solution here was to put the **mod_evasive** configs in the root **httpd.conf** file.

For some unknown reason, the PHP page just ignores the local values mentioned in the virtual host and just relies on the master value.